# Django - Подскажите как отобразить csv таблицу

Tags: django, csv, таблицы

Осваиваю Django, и не могу разобраться в том как отобразить данные с csv таблицы. Пообщался с ChatGPT на эту тему, погуглил, попробовал разные варианты, но таблица не отображается. Есть подозрение, что не правильные пути к файлам.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, что именно я делаю не так.

Таблица должна брать данные из `lp_state_protectorate.csv` и выводить таблицу на странице `sait/table`.

csv файл находится в нескольких местах (Пробовал разные варианты):

- в корневом каталоге.
- `static/csv/lp_state_protectorate.csv`
- `static/main/csv/lp_state_protectorate.csv`

Вот код, который у меня есть в данный момент:

`main\urls.py`:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    # path('news/', views.news_home, name='news_name'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('table/', views.csv_table, name='table'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

`views.py`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
#from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    data = {
        'title': 'Main Page',
        'values': ['Some', 'Hello', '123']
    }
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', data)


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'main/about.html')


def csv_table(request):
    return render(request, 'main/table.html')
```

```html
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="features">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>Table</p>
    <table>
        {% for row in data %}
        <tr>
            {% for cell in row %}
            <td>{{ cell }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

```py
from django.conf import settings
import csv
from django.shortcuts import render

def csv_table(request):
    csv_file_path = settings.BASE_DIR / 'static/csv/lp_state_protectorate.csv'
    with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
        data = list(csv_reader)

    return render(request, 'main/table.html', {'data': data})
```

Answer (score 0):

В целом получилось разобраться. Проблема была в неправильном пути к файлу.

Переместил файл csv файл в корневой каталог, в папку statis/. И изменил путь к этому файлу.